# How do I search for a user in Foursquare using the mLewisLogic python wrapper?

Tags: python, api, foursquare

I'm having some trouble working with the Foursquare API. My end goal is to obtain a user's information (profile stats, twitter ids, facebooks ids, ...) from the Foursquare API. I would like to search for a user by either Twitter ID or name. My first attempt is using the foursquare recommended python wrapper called foursquare. Here is the documentation: https://github.com/mLewisLogic/foursquare

Here is my rather simple code:

```
import foursquare

client_id = xxx
client_secret = yyy

client = foursquare.Foursquare(client_id, client_secret)

print client.users.search(params={'twitter': 'nike'})
```

and here is my error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\nbush\workspace\Foursquare - API\main_foursq.py", line 12, in <module>
    users = client.users.search(params={'twitter': 'nike'})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\foursquare\__init__.py", line 301, in search
    return self.GET('search', params, multi=multi)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\foursquare\__init__.py", line 272, in GET
    return self.requester.GET(self._expanded_path(path), *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\foursquare\__init__.py", line 200, in GET
    result = _get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\foursquare\__init__.py", line 787, in _get
    return _process_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\foursquare\__init__.py", line 822, in _process_response
    return _raise_error_from_response(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\foursquare\__init__.py", line 834, in 
  _raise_error_from_response
    raise exc(meta.get('errorDetail'))
foursquare.NotAuthorized: A user is required to call this endpoint.
```

Any help would be great. Also if there is a better API or an easier way to do this with urllib2 or something then any suggestions would be appreciated. Alos, does anyone know if mLewisLogic is up to date with foursquare API v2? And is there a more complete documentation? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add access_token

```
client = foursquare.Foursquare(client_id, client_secret, **access_token**)
```